# php mail() not working in IIS 6

Tags: php, iis-6

HI
my code

```
$send_contact=mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);

if($send_contact){

    echo "mail was sent successfully";

}

else{

    echo "mail could not be send";

}
```

in not working in IIS6 for windows server. It sends success message but email is not sent
http://interfacenepal.com/contact/contact.php
phpinfo details can be found at 
http://interfacenepal.com/contact/testing.php

Comment: How do you know the e-mail was not sent? or not received by mail client?

Comment: I know because i set the email to be sent myself and i am not getting emails thougn browser shows that email has been successfully sent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't mention what version of PHP you're using, however the `mail()` function in PHP for Windows is a bit buggy (certainly in 5.2.6 to 5.3.0):

> [Bug #28038 Sent incorrect RCPT TO commands to SMTP server](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=28038)

I'd recommend, as others have, using [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) instead.

Comment: PHP Version 4.3.11. Thank you for you suggestion Kev.

Answer (score 3):

The warnings in your test page suggest that you are be using Gmail's SMTP server. Gmail requires both encryption and authentication and these features are not supported by plain mail() function. You need to use a library that implements them, such as [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)- it has more sophisticated means available to send mail should the mail() function fail, and better error support in general...not to mention a whole raft of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Except using Swift Mailer or PHPMailer you need to make sure your server is configured properly to use another server to send emails.